# Tunneling through HTTP

Tags: http, ssl, tcp, tunneling, proxies

**WRITTEN IN JAVA**

Im creating a program that connects to a proxy and then tunneling to another server to send TCP packets, this is my code:

```
{
Socket skt = new Socket(proxy_address, proxy_port);
PrintStream myOutput = new PrintStream(skt.getOutputStream());

String Request = "CONNECT " + host + ":" + 443 + " HTTP/1.0";
String host3 = "Host: " + host + ":" + 443;
myOutput.println(Request + "\r\n" + host3 );
}
```

Trying to find out why im not getting a response from the proxy server.

Comment: What language is your Code. It looks like Java, but to be sure you should tag your question with the language being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two more line endings - one to indicate the end of the `Host:` header, and one for an empty line to indicate the end of the connection request.  Try:

```
myOutput.println(Request + "\r\n" + host3 + "\r\n\r\n");
```

Comment: I actually have one more question, when i start sending the packets i want to the server do i need to do anything special to it? like adding the empty line at the end?

Comment: @Masterban: No, after you read the response headers from the server (which are terminated with an empty line), if the response code was 200 then you'll have a raw connection with the other side.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try and take a look at either [corkscrew](http://www.agroman.net/corkscrew/) or [Proxytunnel](http://proxytunnel.sourceforge.net/), although these are basically SSH over HTTP(S) proxies.